# выводить картинки на сайт WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Учился натягивать шаблон на WP, и появилась надобность выводить картинки в специальный блок, все стили для картинок уже прописаны, нужно сделать так, чтобы  в блок добавлялись картинки средствами вордпресс. Как можно это реализовать?
(Гуглил, но видим неправильно)

Comment: так вам в этом блоке нужно добавлять изображения или выводить?

Comment: @alenkins выводить в блоке, добавлять в админке wp

Answer (score 0):

плагин PODs.  developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/